# pygtk how to embed external application within my pygtk GUI

Tags: python, pygtk, embedding

I'm desiging a pygtk GUI and want to embed an external application into it.

Does anyone have any idea how this can be done?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by 'embed'?  Could you be more specific about your situation?

Comment: What do you mean by "embed".
Be more specific and give examples.

Comment: I've done this before in Gambas2. It should look like this
http://upload.snelhest.org/images/0812134.png
You can see in the screenshot how gparted embeds into my application.

by 'embed' I mean launch an external application... but instead of having the window manager decorate it and place it on the desktop, it needs to go right into my application. 

Think of it like doing a reparent but on a window not a widget

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what application you are trying to embed into yours, but if the other app is a GTK app (or one that supports the XEMBED protocol), you should be able to do this with [gtk.Plug](https://developer-old.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gtkplug.html) and [gtk.Socket](https://developer-old.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gtksocket.html). The PyGTK tutorial has a section explaining how to do this:

[PyGTK 2.0 Tutorial - Plugs and Sockets](https://web.archive.org/web/20040918150911/http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/sec-PlugsAndSockets.html) from Wayback Machine (archive.org)

Comment: I did look at that, but I just dont see how that would help me embed an external application.

The window ID reported by xwinfo is something like 0x12343 but the plug wants a window ID in a LONG format... I dont know how to fit these 2 pieces together

Answer (score 1):

You don't use an external program to get the `gtk.Plug`/`gtk.Socket` ID, they have their respective functions for that. See this tutorial for examples:

[PyGTK 2.0 Tutorial - Plugs and Sockets link](https://web.archive.org/web/20040918150911/http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/sec-PlugsAndSockets.html) from Wayback Machine (archive.org).

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to reparent an external window (that may not be a gtk window), you can use

```
w = gdk.window_foreign_new(window_id)
```

to get a gdk window object from an operating system window handle, and then use

```
w.reparent(parent_window, x, y)
```

to reparent it into an existing gtk container.